SFTP using Jump/bastion Server using public key authentication
Let assume that I have a client machine C, a jump server J, and a destination server D. I want a setup where I connect/SFTP with C -> D via J. It is working with password authentication and ProxyJump attribute. Here is my local ssh config file.
Host j-host
  HostName 192.168.90.3
  User alpha
  IdentityFile /Users/my/.ssh/id_ed25519
    
Host d-host
  HostName 192.168.90.4
  User alpha
  ProxyJump j-host

I have a user called alpha, created a user account on J and D server with limited permissions. alpha has it own keys on J.
What I want is, J should have authorized public key of C, and D should have authorized  public key of J, but when I try, D is excepting public key of C.
#D's sshd_config file

Match User alpha
#       AuthorizedKeysFile /home/alpha/.ssh/authorized_keys  #(tried this)
        ChrootDirectory /var/www/
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
        PasswordAuthentication yes
        PubkeyAuthentication no

If D is already authorizing C, then is defeating the purpose of J. Am I missing something basic here?

I want this setup to be used with SFTP clients like FileZilla or CyberDuck. So I can't ssh to the J and from there I access the D's SFTP cli.


Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's off-topic here.

@MartinPrikryl Thanks for suggestion, posted on Super User, It is not allowing me to delete, as It has 1 answer :(

Yes you misunderstand the purpose of a jump host, it's only purpose is  to allow your client to use an alternate route to the destination.
The destination host doesn't know and shouldn't know anything about a jump host.
The destination host always checks the client's authorization, not which route the client used.
A jump host itself doesn't have credentials for the destination host nor can it access the credentials of the client.
It is often used to reach a server that is otherwise not directly accessible.
